# windows sync center error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: windows, sync

When i press offline available on a folder on LAN then its start syncing but nothing syncs and gives error for each file in folder `"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."`

Comment: Look through Sync Center settings to see what else is using it.  Look in Windows File Explorer to see if it has files open.

Comment: May be a few, but all files in folder are not open else where. for example pdf files... there are more than 100 files in folder and its sync nothing and give error for each file that "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Comment: This is not a Windows systemic issue.  Try running DISM / SFC .....   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
  .... If that does not work and if your files are not busy, then you may need more in-depth repairs.

Comment: This is fresh windows re-installed a few days ago.

Comment: Sorry then, I do not know. Not happening here on my 2 Production Windows 11 Pro machines.

Comment: I did this all (sfc /scannow repaired some files) but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit were OneDrive and GoogleDrive. I paused their autosyncing feature before make the folder/files available offline.